# How do you use/make CSS based buttons?

Tags: css, button

'd like to have one image for the background and then reuse that for any size button with any text on it by just using a CSS class. So, I'd like to have the button, the moused-over and clicked button as images, but then use CSS to apply that to a button so that I can change the text in the HTML (rather than having to recreate the button image everytime the text changes or I need a new button with new text). Also, that'll allow me to change the color of ALL buttons in one place.

I do web development only part time, so a bit of a newbie at the CSS stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a good tutorial for creating CSS buttons - http://designshack.co.uk/articles/css/6-useful-css-button-recipes-you-can-copy-paste